# How to properly use DOMDocument->ReplaceChild in combination with DOMDocument->getElementById?

Tags: php, domdocument

```
public function DOMChangeElementContent($Element,$NewContent)
{
    //Pull the original element from the currently loaded DOM document
    $OriginalElement = $this->DOM->getElementById($Element); 
    //Create a new element 
    $NewElement = $this->DOM->createElement($Element, $NewContent);

    //Replace the old element with the new element
    $this->DOM->DOMreplaceChild($NewElement, $OriginalElement);     
}
```

For some reason I keep getting the 'original element could not be found' element even though I'm pulling it off the same document I'm trying to replace it in. Am I using it in a wrong way somehow? None of the questions  answered here quite explained what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Check `$OriginalElement` after you do `getElementById` and see if it's correctly returning the element.

Comment: $OriginalElement does return the correct element, DOMreplaceChild still refuses to replace it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`replaceChild` is a method of `DOMNode`, not of the document itself. You have to call it on the parent node of the element you want to replace:

```
$OriginalElement->parentNode->DOMreplaceChild($NewElement, $OriginalElement);
```

Comment: So that's why! Thank you very much -- this explained everything.